# C# - DisplayDialog() Not Working on FileSave and Drag/Drop

Tags: c#, winforms, crash, save

I have a successful build using some screenshot code, and got drag and drop working (but have no code from there), and I'm trying to display a message **on a form** after the file saves successfully, or if you drag and drop too many files. I don't want to use `MessageBox.Show` (even tho this method works if I replace the code) because I want to use a check mark picture and a button to open the file of the screenshot location. My problem is after the screenshot saves, a line in `from#.designer.cs` crashes. I've looked all over for how to remedy this, and no help. I don't watch to touch the `Form3.Designer.cs` file because comments say to not to. My code is listed below.

Screenshot/Screen Cap code in Form 1:

```
        private void saveScreenshotToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // ** SAVE A SCREENSHOT *** (Working)
        Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(this.Width, this.Height);
        DrawToBitmap(bitmap, new Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height));
        bitmap.Save((boxFileName.Text) + "_ScreenCap.JPEG",ImageFormat.Jpeg);

       // If i replace the following 2 lines with MessageBox.Show("FileSave successful"); it works fine. Why is this code not working????

        Form3 f3 = new Form3();
        f3.ShowDialog();

    }
```

Code that crashes in `Form3.Designer.CS`

```
        // Form3
        // 
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(292, 121);
        this.Controls.Add(this.button1);
        this.Controls.Add(this.label2);
        this.Controls.Add(this.label1);
        this.Controls.Add(this.pictureBox1);
        this.MaximizeBox = false;
        this.MaximumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(300, 150);
        this.MinimizeBox = false;
        this.MinimumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(300, 150);
        this.Name = "Form3";
        this.ShowIcon = false;
        this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
        this.Text = "ScreenCap Result";
        this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Form3_Load);

        /// the following line crashed

        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.performanceCounter1)).EndInit();

        // end line that crashed

        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.pictureBox1)).EndInit();
        this.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.PerformLayout();
```

Here is the code from DragDrop:

```
void Form1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        var files = (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop);
        if (files.Length == 1)
        {
            /// WORKING

            MessageBox.Show("Reading files from Drag and Drop not fully implimentd.");
        }
        else
        {
            // NOT WORING (crashes)

            Form3 f3 = new Form3();
            f3.ShowDialog();
        }
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Well, what exception causes it to crash? What does the text tell you?

Comment: Can you open Form3.cs in the designer or does it crash as well?

Comment: @ThomasWeller No. It successfully compiles. It only crashes when the event triggers it once the app is running.

Comment: @ThomasWeller I get this error with the line of code highlighted. https://www.dropbox.com/s/v6wm8kbvt9k8y7k/CS_CRASH.png?dl=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what was causing the issue. I had to delete the `perfomanceCounter1` object out of the Embedded Object window, and the issue of the app crashing went away. I must more be careful what I add for embedded objects.

Answer (score 0):

The error message on the screenshot you linked to says

> InvalidOperationException
>
> Additional information: failed to initialize because the CategoryName is missing.

[image: Part of the screenshot provided by OP]

It seems that Microsoft forgot to document that exception on the [EndInit()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.performancecounter.endinit(v=vs.110).aspx) call, but that's not the first one.

Therefore, on `performanceCounter1`, which I assume is of type [PerformanceCounter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.diagnostics.performancecounter(v=vs.110).aspx) you need to provide a value to the property [CategoryName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.performancecounter.categoryname(v=vs.110).aspx).

You can do that without modifying the `Form3.Designer.cs` file manually. Instead, open `Form3` in the designer, select `performanceCounter1` and select a value from the list as shown in the following screenshot:

[image: Select a value from the list of performance counters]